# Selecting SUM+COUNT from one table and COUNT from another in Single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to fetch Sum of age and total users which are active from `users` table and total number of png pictures from `pictures` table. I tried the following but it is giving me error. How can i do this in single query? I'm using PDO

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(age) AS age_sum,COUNT(*) AS total FROM users where type='active'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS pictotal FROM pictures where extension='png')
```

#### ERROR -> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: what's the error you are getting back?

Comment: @BWS error-> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: does each select return correct response on it's own?

Comment: @BWS Seperately they are working fine , when i run second row containg SUM & COUNT it works fine , but when i put the three in select it showserror

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT
 
 AA.age_sum, AA. total, BB.pictotal 
FROM
 (SELECT SUM(age) AS age_sum,COUNT(*) AS total FROM users where type='active') AA,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS pictotal FROM pictures where extension='png') BB

Answer (score 1):

For your task is a Sub Select the better decision - like this

```
SELECT SUM(age) AS age_sum,COUNT(*) AS total, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pictures where extension='png') AS pictotal FROM users where type='active')
```

You simple can't "merge" two different querys in one query when the amount of columns, that are returned from each query, are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

You did it
This select is your problem  returns 2 columns
     (SELECT SUM(age) AS age_sum,COUNT(*) AS total

```
 SELECT SUM(age) AS age_sum,COUNT(*) AS total, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pictures where extension='png') AS pictotal
 FROM users where type='active'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT 'AGE_SUM',SUM(age) FROM users where type='active'
UNION
SELECT 'TOTAL',COUNT(*) FROM users where type='active'
UNION
SELECT 'PIC_TOTAL',COUNT(*) FROM pictures where extension='png'
```

Comment: i upvoted your answer because with ``UNION`` the other querys are executed - with subselect only if the main table contains data

Comment: Why to do this to RUN TWICE the SUM and COUNT ?SELECT 'AGE_SUM',SUM(age) FROM users where type='active'
UNION
SELECT 'TOTAL',COUNT(*) FROM users where type='active'

Comment: @ins0 main table contains data means?

Comment: with the subquery method - the subquery is only executed when the table ``users`` contains user with type ``active`` - if not nothing is returned

Comment: @BWS I used your query it is showing sum as zero and TOTAL & PIC_TOTAL as undefined index